# html js not valid error message still appearing when input is correct

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following input field with js validation to input a name and when the field is left blank an error message appears which is what I required however when I enter a name it accepts the input in my form however the same error message pops up stil briefly.

```js
function myFunction() {

  let x = document.getElementsByName("first_name")[0].value;

  let text;
  text = "";
  if (x == '' || x == null) {
    text = "Input not valid";
  }
  document.getElementById("first_name_errors").innerHTML = text;
}

document.addEventListener('invalid', (function() {
  return function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementsByName("first_name").focus();
  };
})(), true);
```

```html
<input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="first name" name class="input_fields" required>
<div class="error-message" id="first_name_errors"></div>
<input class="save_btn" type="submit" value="Save" name="save_fname" onclick="myFunction()">
```

How can i fix this?

Moroever, I intend to use this template for other fields such as email and password fields assuming that the main part of this code I need to focus adapting is?:

```
let text;
  if (x == '' ||  x == null) {
    text = "Input not valid";
  }
```

Help/advice is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You might consider reading this document: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Constraint_validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to take the first element of the NodeList returned by `getElementsByName("first_name")`

Like this:

```
let x = document.getElementsByName("first_name")[0].value;
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tried this but now I see the message appears as 'undefined' - any idea how to hide this?

Comment: Yes its because you have no default text defined. The code inside your if statement is not being executed because its no error. You have to assign something to the variable 'text' before your if statement if you want to display something else.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help and advice - I now have this working as wanted! I'll accept your answer and update my code above with the changes. Thanks again

Comment: Glad I helped you out. But I think it's better not to update your code above, for others to be able to follow the question.